# Vuejs scrolled height returns 0

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Am using vuejs2 with codeigniter.

I have added the following to the html

```
<div class="container">
    ...content here
</div>
```

In a separate  scripts.js i have

```
script.js

new Vue({
 el: '.container',
 methods:{
    handleScroll:function(event){
      console.log("scrolled to", document.body.scrollTop);
      },
  },
created() {
 window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll,true);
},
});
```

Am trying to get the position on y axis that the user has scrolled to but keep on getting 0. What am i missing out.
I have included [This Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVaELL)

Comment: I'd use the `mounted()` hook to add document event listeners, `created()` is probably executing too early

Comment: Even after changing to mounted am still getting 0

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I guess the real issue is that the `<body>` is not the element that is scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you've misunderstood the usage of scrollTop.

to get the current scroll position, use `window.scrollY` instead

```
  console.log("scrolled to", window.scrollY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the mounted() hook instead of the created().

The created() is executed when your Vue component is created, but this doens't mean the DOM element is there. So mounted() is when your Vue component was created and already mounted to the DOM.